# How to stop blinking borders on javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I hope you can help me out on this one.. How can I make this code stop in 3 or 4 seconds?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("my").style.borderColor = "red";
    }, 1000);
}, 500);

setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("my").style.borderColor = "blue";
}, 1000);

}
```

Comment: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.clearInterval.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) method:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(blueInterval);
    clearInterval(redInterval);
}, timeToBlink);
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neustroev_ai/gwt75cof/

Answer (score 0):

```
    var blinks=5;
    var myBlink = setInterval(function() { blink(); },1000);

    function blink() {
        switch(document.getElementById("my").style.borderColor)
        {
                case("red"):
                    document.getElementById("my").style.borderColor = "blue";
                    break;
                default:
                case("blue"):
                    document.getElementById("my").style.borderColor = "red";
                    break;
        }
        blinks--;
        if(blinks<=0)
        {
            clearInterval(myBlink);
        }
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sp8h7orh/2/